# What is this cipher?

Tags: cipher

I need to decode this but I don't know which cipher,  anybody can help?

> ++++++++++[>+>+++>+++++++>++++++++++<<<<-]>>>++.--------------------.+++++++++++++++.++++++++.<+++++++++++++++++++++.>+++++++.---------------.<+.>++++++++.<-.

Answer (score 13):

It is [brainfuck](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/) (a computing language)
 for

> H4CK3RC4K3

or

> Hacker cake